# Why is my variable "let" printing b instead of a?

Tags: python

For a given string in enumerate() function, while i=0, it should print the first element. But I don't understand why this time it is printing the second element. To my eyes, in the first iteration when i=0, it should've printed 'a' for a given string('abc'). But it is printing 'b' instead. Help me understand. Also how in the first iteration, the value of s[:i] is 'b', when i=0?

```
def permute(s):
    out = []

    # Base Case
    if len(s) == 1:
        out = [s]

    else:
        # For every letter in string
        for i, let in enumerate(s):

        # Step 2 and 3 

            for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
                print ("current i is:", i)
                print ("current let is:", let)
                print ("current perm is:", perm)
                print ("current s[:i] is:", s[:1])

                # Add it to output
                out += [let + perm]
                print("current out is", out)
                print("\n")

    return out

permute('abc')
```

Comment: You have a recursion in `for perm in permute(..)`, so if you follow the call-stack, it will do a recursion with `bc` and then `c`. Try firing up a debugger and follow the execution through your code. The recursion with `c` just returns `['c']` which is then `perm` in the recursion where `s` is `bc`... if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't ans my question. I understood the recursion part. I need to understand why in the first iteration let is b. to my eyes let should return a. also how s[:i] is 'b', when i=0?

Comment: When `permute('abc')` you assign `(i, let) = (0, 'a')`. Then `permute('bc')` (recursion) and assign `(i, let) = (0, 'b')`. Then `permute('c')` which returns `['c']`. Now you're returned to where `(i, let) = (0, 'b')` and then you print. It is not until this function call ends, that you're returned to where `(i, let) = (0, 'a')`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand fully now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of pseudocode to illustrate what is going wrong.

```
for perm in permute( s[:0] + s[1:] = 'bc'):
    for i, let in enumerate('bc'):
        for perm in permute ('bc'[:i] + 'bc'[i+1:]):
            print stuff

            #print(i=0)
            #print(let = b)
            #print(perm = c)
            #printinseconditeration(i=1, let = c, perm=b)
```

In other words, your permutations do not start where you think them to start because of the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

When, within your `enumerate` loop, you call `permute`, it actually re-run what you just did and the state is not anymore what you thought it was...:

```
def permute(s):
    out = []

    # Base Case
    if len(s) == 1:
        out = [s]

    else:
        # For every letter in string
        for i, let in enumerate(s):
            print 'If this is a first call to permute, things are like you expect...'
            print 'Otherwise, something looks weird ;-)'
            print ("current i is:", i)
            print ("current let is:", let)
            print ("current s[:i] is:", s[:1])
        # Step 2 and 3
            for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
                print 'This only comes after another call to permute'

                print ("current i is:", i)
                print ("current let is:", let)
                print ("current s[:i] is:", s[:1])

                # Add it to output
                out += [let + perm]

    return out

permute('abc')
# If this is a first call to permute, things are like you expect...
# Otherwise, something looks weird ;-)
# ('current i is:', 0)
# ('current let is:', 'a')
# ('current s[:i] is:', 'a')
# If this is a first call to permute, things are like you expect...
# Otherwise, something looks weird ;-)
# ('current i is:', 0)
# ('current let is:', 'b')
# ('current s[:i] is:', 'b')
# This only comes after another call to permute
# ('current i is:', 0)
# ('current let is:', 'b')
# ('current s[:i] is:', 'b')
# etc...
```

Not too sure what you want to achieve, but removing the recursive call to `permute` seems a good idea to me:

```
def permute(s):
    # Base Case
    if len(s) == 1:
        out = [s]
    else:
        out = []
        for i, let in enumerate(s):
            print ("current i is:", i)
            print ("current let is:", let)
            print ("current s[:i] is:", s[:1])
            out += [let + s[:i] + s[i+1:]]
            print("current out is", out)
            print("\n")
    return out


foo = permute('abc')
print foo
# ['abc', 'bac', 'cab']
```